# How do I select a second element within a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created the following code (which works fine) that adds a class to sort icon and a column on click. It's a grid fix.

The following code:

```
    /* Update sort icon (Ascending or descending) based on saved sort setting */
    updateSortIcon: function (containerConfiguration) {
    /* update sort direction icon based on stored sort setting; Sort setting is stored in the database */
    var classElement = $('td[class$=' + containerConfiguration.GridReportInfo.SortingInfo.AnalyticUniqueId + ']');
    if (this.validChildElement(classElement)) {
        var indicatorElement = classElement.next()[0].children[0];
        var newIndicatorClass;
        var newParentIndicatorClass;
        switch (containerConfiguration.GridReportInfo.SortingInfo.SortDirection) {
            case ('ASC'):
            case 0:
                newIndicatorClass = 'GOSort1Right GOImage column-bg-color-asc';
                newParentIndicatorClass = 'column-bg-color-asc';
                break;
            case ('DESC'):
            case 1:
                newIndicatorClass = 'GOSort4Right GOImage column-bg-color-desc';
                newParentIndicatorClass = 'column-bg-color-desc';
                break;
            default:
                newIndicatorClass = 'GOSort0Right GOImage';
                newParentIndicatorClass = '';
                break;
        }
        classElement.first().removeClass('column-bg-color-desc column-bg-color-asc').addClass(newParentIndicatorClass);
        indicatorElement.setAttribute('class', newIndicatorClass);
    }
},
```

This code applies **column-bg-color-asc** to the first table cell and the icon but how can I add the class **column-bg-color-asc** to the second table cell?

```
<td id="ext-gen1559" class="GOWrap0 GOAlignCenter GOHeaderText GOCellHeader GONoRight HideCol0ext-gen28361395166306 column-bg-color-asc">No. of Positions</td>



<td class=" GOCellHeader GONoLeft GOAlignRight GOHeaderButton"> 

<u class="GOSort1Right GOImage column-bg-color-asc">﻿</u>
</td>
```

Comment: Table cell means ? you mean td or tr?

Comment: A table cell (as shown in my example) is always a TD or a TH. Not TR. My example shows TD

Answer (score 1):

if it is the second cell in each row then:

```
$("#tableId> tbody > tr").each(function() { 
$(this).find("td:nth(1)").addClass('column-bg-color-asc');
});
```

the code above gets the table rows. then iterates on each row and gets the second cell. on that cell it adds the class.